# Spring Zuul route strip one '/' in 'http://' of path param

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm sorry for my English that might not express clearly my problem.

I'm using [thumbor](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor) for cropping image, e.g: `http://thumbor-server/unsafe/300x200/http://192.168.99.100/images/image1.jpg`

I also use nginx to route request to thumbor, e.g. request `http://192.168.1.100/image-service/unsafe/300x200/http://192.168.99.100/images/image1.jpg`
will be routed to `http://thumbor-server/unsafe/300x200/http://192.168.99.100/images/image1.jpg`.

But for some reasons, I have to use Spring zuul to do the routing instead of nginx. So I config the route filter like this:

`zuul:
  ignored-services: '*'
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  routes:
    image-service:
      path: /image-service/**
      url: http://thumbor-server`

But after routing by zuul, thumbor cannot load image from `http://192.168.99.100/images/image1.jpg` because url of the image is stripped one '/' in 'http://', so thumbor displays an error indicates that 'http:/192.168.99.100/images/image1.jpg' is an invalid path.

I have to work around by remove 'http://' in url of the image.

Is there a config that Zuul not strip a '/' in 'http://' in url of routing request?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you didn't proxy /images/**, you can try by add those below:

`routes:
   images:
      path: /images/**
      stripPrefix: false
      url: http://thumbor-server`